# How to make a paragraph-granularity-editable document in GWT with paragraph meta-data

Tags: html, gwt

I want a UI that is basically a document having souped-up paragraphs that are (a) editable and (b) each have a column of meta-data/widgets on their left.  That is, I want a tree layout that looks like an HTML document, except:

1. to the left of each paragraph is a column of controls like buttons, state indicators, very short textbox fields (3 chars), and
2. if you click on a paragraph (or hit an edit button on the left) it morphs into a textarea you can edit; when you are done, you hit a done button on the left (probably the edit button morphed into a done button) and the textarea goes back to being a paragraph.

When you hit edit, some labels in the meta-data on the left should also morph into text areas, etc. and back again when you hit done.  Also, I want to be able to hit a button and show only part of the paragraph (imagine a paragraph having a title and a body).

I'm sure I can cobble something together that does this if I hit it over the head with enough HTML tables and GWT Panels, but I'm trying to do this in as lightweight manner as possible, given that such documents of these things may be large, I want it to resize naturally in the browser, and since browsers already naturally lay out things that look like documents I should be able to use very vanilla HTML for most of it.

I've spent several days being frustrated with GWT Panels of various kinds.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to hide a `Label` and show a `TextArea`, and then switch back when you're done editing. Set whatever styles you need to on them - I think a `Label` comes out as a `<div>` and a `TextArea` comes out as a `<textarea>`.  No panels required... just a `<div>` container to put these two widgets in.

Comment: Right, but how do I put the column of meta-data widgets on the left?  I want something that lines up with the top of the paragraph.  I was thinking to just use a table with two columns and one row and put the paragraph in the second column and the widgets in the first; that seems to work, but not sure how to float the widgets to the top of the table cell and not sure if I need a table at all as it will be a lot of tables.

Comment: Put the meta-data widgets in a div and the text in a div and then style the two divs so that they line up next to each other.